# Creating Material Design SearchView which is always collapsed

Tags: android, material-design, searchview

I am working on a material design app and i want to implement a `ToolBar` which needs a collapsed `SearchView` and a settings button. I've successfully implemented the `SearchView` and settings menu items. But the problem is that I want the SearchView to be collapsed by default.Now it is collapsed on icon click only.

Code:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
    } 

 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (id == R.id.action_search) {
                final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
                SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.navigationdrawer.MainActivity" >


   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you include your menu xml file?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please see updated question

Comment: Try using "collapse" instead of "always".

Comment: @Varundroid You mean `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"` ?

Comment: Yes that's it. Did it work?

Comment: No. Now the icon itself is missing

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

If you want it to always show, but be expandable as explained in the [action views training](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html) and the [Providing Search with SearchView video](https://youtu.be/9OWmnYPX1uc)